# InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int32 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Mul]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got this error. The code works in another person's google colab. But it doesn't work in my colab. I wonder it is related to my colab environment. I use python 3.7

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
693       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
694         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 695           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
696         else:
697           raise

InvalidArgumentError: in user code:

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/CGL/loss.py:5 medical_codes_loss  *
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred), axis=1))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:246 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2
    logits=logits, labels=labels, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:148 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
    relu_logits - logits * labels,
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1367 binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1710 _mul_dispatch
    return multiply(x, y, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:530 multiply
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:6236 mul
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:6941 raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
<string>:3 raise_from
    

InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int32 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Mul]
```

Comment: Can you please share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: have the same problem